# Hide a specific cell in my table

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to hide a specific cell in my table view?

```
private var yourDataSource = [AccountData.AllTasksDB] //A Json Array originally

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    var rowHeight:CGFloat = 72

    //AccountData.AllTasksDB[indexPath.row]["importantvariable"]
    if (self.yourDataSource[indexPath.row]["importantvarible"] == "0")
    {
        print("Cell is mine")
        rowHeight = 0
    }
    else
    {
        print("Cell is not mine")
        rowHeight = 72.0
    }

    return rowHeight
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I thought it was looping through each cell and checking a value i've setup before hand. But it doesn't seem to want to access it.

Comment: I would suggest saving the indexPath of the cell(s) you want to hide and then reload the table to determine the rowHeight

Comment: `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)` might be returning nil because the cell has been dequeued...

Comment: Example: `fileprivate var self.hiddenCellIndexes.contains:[IndexPath]` then in your tableView heightForRow delegate : `if self.hiddenCellIndexes.contains(indexPath)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I figured this would be more legible in an answer*

```
fileprivate var yourDataSource = [YourObject]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

  if self.yourDataSource[indexPath].isMine == true {

    return 0
  }
  else
  {
    return 72.0    //or whatever you like
  }
}
```

Comment: Just be sure to append/remove the indexes as needed, then call `self.tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: I've updated my code. But it's still not seeing the cell's variables (cell.isMine from the TableViewCellMyTasks class). I'm trying to see if a variable there is true, and if so, set the cell's height to 0 (Basically hide it)

Comment: I don't suggest that you access the properties of the cells themselves. You should use your dataSource (which is used to populate the cells, right?), to determine the height. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Ok, I'll focus on the datasource. It doesn't like "if (self.yourDataSource[indexPath.row]["importantvariable"] == "0")" or that I'm using a string to reference "importantvariable". Am I formatting this incorrectly?

Comment: I think you would want `self.yourDataSource[indexPath].importantvariable == "whatever"`

Comment: Got it -- Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing cell in the `tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method.
At this point the cell is not yet visible (or dequeued). If the cell is not visible, it will be nil, hence your error.

Try putting a break point at `let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! TableViewCellMyTasks` and you'll see that it is nil.